# angularjs - Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code:

```
var getserverstatus = function () {
            $http.get(FSERVERSTATUS)
                .then(function (data) {
                    data.data.forEach(function (staItem) {
                        if (!$scope.serverInfo.data.hasOwnProperty(staItem.hostId)) {
                            console.log(staItem);
                        }
                        else {
                            staItem.changeNum = 1;
                            angular.extend($scope.serverInfo.data [staItem.hostId], staItem);
                            // angular.extend($scope.listInfo.data [staItem.id], {changeNum:1});
                        }
                    });
                })
        };
        getserverstatus();
```

My browser shows this error:

```
Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
```

I'm using `angularjs`.

Comment: It's telling you that `$scope.serverInfo` does not have `.data`. Check your assumptions, `console.log($scope.serverInfo)` before that to make sure you have what you think you have.

Comment: @Amadan he might have data property in the object, but its set to undefined.

Comment: And also "data.data.forEach(function (staItem) {" data has repeated twice

Comment: Usually, a `Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined` error when you use `foo.bar` means that foo doesn't exist, or is empty. I would suggest to go back to the part of your code where `foo` is supposed to be created or filled up and check what's going on. `console.log` and the devtools breakpoints are your friends. :)

Comment: @Amadan - i don't know angular, but `!$scope.serverInfo.data` have nothing to do with the returned data object from .get()?

Comment: @YanMayatskiy: Oh derp, you are totally right.

Comment: @NagaveerGowda data.data is data property in the data object from .get()